# Number of bit strings of length 8 that do not contain "$100$"?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, inclusion-exclusion

I am thinking the total number of possible strings is $2^8$ and the number of strings with $100$ at the beginning would be $2^8 - 2^3 = 2^5$. Now "$100$" can shift across the string $5$ times going to the right. Is the answer then $2^8 - 2^5 \times 5$?

Comment: You are overcounting the bad strings.  Specifically, you count the strings $100100xx$ twice.

Comment: @lulu So we minus 2^2?

Comment: No.  It's much worse than that...you have to add back every double counted string (since $8<3\times3$ you can't have triply counted strings).  Thus you have to enumerate all the patterns in which $100$ appears twice.  Perfectly possible, because $8$ is quite small.  Hard to generalize this approach to longer strings though.

Comment: 2^8 - 2^3  is not  2^5, the first expression is 248, the letter is 32.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, the straight forward approach as proposed in the question won't work because it multiply counts the bad strings in which $100$ appears more than once (indeed, it counts bad strings once for each appearance of $100$).

For short strings (like length $8$) a more careful count via the principle of Inclusion/Exclusion isn't impossible but it's not exactly easy and, as the length increases, this method gets harder and harder.  I think it's easier to attack the problem recursively.  Toward that end, define some sub-types of the "good" strings of length $n$.  Specifically, let $A_n$ denote those good strings that end in $1$ and let $B_n$ denote those that end in $10$.  Note that the total $T_n$ is then given by $$T_n=A_n+B_n+1$$ where the $1$ comes from the good string $0^n$ which ends in neither $1$ nor $10$.

Recursive, we note that $$A_n=A_{n-1}+B_{n-1}+1=T_{n-1}$$  since you get a good string of length $n$ by appending a $1$ to any good string of length $n-1$.  Similarly $$B_n=A_{n-1}=T_{n-2}$$  Thus $$T_n=T_{n-1}+T_{n-2}+1$$

It is easy to see that $A_1=1$, $A_2=2$, $B_1=0$, $B_2=1$ whence $$\{T_n\}=\{2,4,7,12,20,33,54,88,\cdots\}$$

Consistency Check:  Let's count $T_4,\;T_5,\;T_6$ directly.  There are $16$ strings of length $4$ and the bad ones are $x100$ and $100x$, thus there are $4$ bad strings so $T_4=16-4=12$ as desired.  Similarly the bad strings of length $5$ are $100xx$,  $x100x$, $xx100$ so $T_5=32-12=20$ as desired.  To count the bad strings of length $6$ we have to be a little careful...the patterns are $100xxx$, $x100xx$, $xx100x$, $xxx100$ but we have to add back $1$ for the double counted string $100100$.  Thus $T_6=64-8\times 4+1=33$ as desired.

Induction shows that, in fact, $T_n=F_{n+3}-1$ where $F_i$ denotes the Fibonacci numbers $\{F_i\}_{i=1}^{\infty}=\{1,1,2,3,5,8,13,21,\cdots\}$

Answer (score 3):

Using generating functions  with $z$ for zero and $w$  for ones we get
the generating function

$$(1+z+z^2+\cdots)
\left(\sum_{q\ge 0} ((w+w^2+w^3+\cdots) z)^q\right)
(1+w+w^2+\cdots).$$

This yields

$$\frac{1}{1-z}\left(\sum_{q\ge 0} z^q \frac{w^q}{(1-w)^q}\right)
\frac{1}{1-w}
\\ = \frac{1}{1-z}\frac{1}{1-w}
\frac{1}{1-wz/(1-w)}
\\ = \frac{1}{1-z} \frac{1}{1-w-wz}.$$

As we  are only interested  in the count  we may drop  the distinction
between zeros and ones, getting

$$\frac{1}{1-z} \frac{1}{1-z-z^2}
= \frac{2+z}{1-z-z^2} - \frac{1}{1-z}.$$

Extracting coeffcients from this yields in terms of Fibonacci numbers

$$2F_{n+1} + F_n  - 1
= F_{n+1} + F_{n+2} - 1 = F_{n+3} - 1.$$

We     can     confirm     these     results    using     the     [DFA
method](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1782724/) which yields

```
> GFNC([[1,0,0]], 2,true);
                                   [[1, 0, 0]]

                                   Q[], 0, Q[]

                                  Q[], 1, Q[1]

                                Q[1], 0, Q[1, 0]

                                  Q[1], 1, Q[1]

                             Q[1, 0], 0, Q[1, 0, 0]

                                Q[1, 0], 1, Q[1]

                            Q[1, 0, 0], 0, Q[1, 0, 0]

                            Q[1, 0, 0], 1, Q[1, 0, 0]

                                       1
                              --------------------
                                        2
                              (z - 1) (z  + z - 1)
```

This  link  includes an  explanation  of  the Goulden-Jackson  cluster
method by @MarkusScheuer.

Using inclusion-exclusion we have for the location of the forbidden
pattern  when  $n=8$  the possibilities  $(1),(2),(3),\ldots,(6)$  and
$(1,4),(2,5),(3,6)$ and $(1,5),(2,6)$ and $(1,6).$ We thus obtain

$$2^8 - 6\times 2^5 + 6\times 2^2 = 88.$$

**We can generalize  the inclusion-exclusion argument.** Suppose we
have $q$ instances of the pattern where $q\le\lfloor n/3\rfloor.$ This
leaves $n-3q$ free slots that  must be distributed in the $q+1$ spaces
between / surrounding the patterns. By stars and bars this can be done
in the following number of ways:

$${n-3q+q\choose q} = {n-2q\choose q}.$$

We thus obtain by inclusion-exclusion the closed form

$$\sum_{q=0}^{\lfloor n/3\rfloor} {n-2q\choose q} (-1)^q
2^{n-3q}.$$

We can evaluate this with the Egorychev method. Introduce

$${n-2q\choose q} = {n-2q\choose n-3q}
= \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{1}{z^{n-3q+1}} (1+z)^{n-2q} \; dz.$$

Observe that this  vanishes when $3q\gt n$ so we  may extend the range
of $q$ to infinity, getting for the sum

$$\frac{2^n}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{1}{z^{n+1}} (1+z)^{n} 
\sum_{q\ge 0} \frac{z^{3q}}{(1+z)^{2q}} (-1)^q 2^{-3q}
\; dz
\\ = \frac{2^n}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{1}{z^{n+1}} (1+z)^{n} 
\frac{1}{1+2^{-3}z^3/(1+z)^2}
\; dz
\\ = \frac{2^n}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{1}{z^{n+1}} (1+z)^{n+2} 
\frac{1}{1+2z+z^2+2^{-3}z^3}
\; dz.$$

Now put $z/(1+z) = w$ so that $z = w/(1-w)$ and
$1+z = 1/(1-w)$ and $dz = 1/(1-w)^2 \; dw$ and

$$1+2z+z^2+2^{-3}z^3 = \frac{1}{8}
\frac{(w-2)(w^2+2w-4)}{(1-w)^3}$$

which yields for the integral

$$\frac{2^n}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\gamma} \frac{1}{w^{n+1}} 
\frac{1}{1-w} \frac{8(1-w)^3}{(w-2)(w^2+2w-4)}
\frac{1}{(1-w)^2} \; dw
\\ = \frac{2^n}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\gamma} \frac{1}{w^{n+1}} 
\frac{8}{(w-2)(w^2+2w-4)} \; dw.$$

This is

$$2^n [w^n] \frac{8}{(w-2)(w^2+2w-4)}
= [w^n] \frac{8}{(2w-2)(4w^2+4w-4)}
\\ = [w^n] \frac{1}{(w-1)(w^2+w-1)}
\\ = [w^n] \frac{1}{(1-w)(1-w-w^2)}.$$

This is the  same generating function as what  we obtained earlier and
the argument is concluded.

**Addendum.** Wilf also succeeds here. We have the generating function

$$\sum_{n\ge 0} z^n 2^n
\sum_{q=0}^{\lfloor n/3\rfloor} {n-2q\choose n-3q} (-1)^q 2^{-3q}
= \sum_{q\ge 0} 2^{-3q} (-1)^q
\sum_{n\ge 3q} z^n 2^n {n-2q\choose n-3q}
\\ = \sum_{q\ge 0} 2^{-3q} (-1)^q
\sum_{n\ge 0} z^{n+3q} 2^{n+3q} {n+q\choose n}
= \sum_{q\ge 0} z^{3q} (-1)^q
\sum_{n\ge 0} z^{n} 2^{n} {n+q\choose n}
\\ = \sum_{q\ge 0} z^{3q} (-1)^q \frac{1}{(1-2z)^{q+1}}
= \frac{1}{1-2z} \frac{1}{1+z^3/(1-2z)}
\\ = \frac{1}{1-2z+z^3}.$$

This is the same generating function as before, done.

Comment: Nice elaboration (+1) :-)

Comment: This is more interesting than it might at first appear because it is an example of a binomial sum where coefficient extraction of formal power series alone does not suffice for evaluation and we need a substitution in the integral including the differential.

Comment: Yes, it's really somewhat more challenging than I thought! Thanks for pointing to it.

Comment: I suspect Wilf might also succeed here.

Answer (score 1):

A nice technique is the so-called *[Goulden-Jackson Cluster Method](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/9806036)* which is a convenient method to derive a *[generating function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_function)* for problems of this kind.

> We consider words of length $n\geq 0$ built from an alphabet $$\mathcal{V}=\{0,1\}$$ and the set $\mathcal{B}=\{100\}$ of *bad* words which are not allowed to be part of the words we are looking for.
>
> We derive a function $F(x)$ with the coefficient of $x^n$ being  the number of wanted words of length $n$.
>   According to the paper (p.7) the generating function $F(x)$  is
>   \begin{align*}
> F(x)=\frac{1}{1-dx-\text{weight}(\mathcal{C})}
> \end{align*}
>   with $d=|\mathcal{V}|=2$, the size of the alphabet and with the *weight-numerator* $\mathcal{C}$ with
>   \begin{align*}
> \text{weight}(\mathcal{C})=\text{weight}(\mathcal{C}[100])
> \end{align*}
>
> We calculate according to the paper
>   \begin{align*}
> \text{weight}(\mathcal{C}[100])&=-x^3
> \end{align*}

It follows:

> A generating function $F(x)$ for the number of words built from $\{0,1\}$ which do *not* contain the subword $100$ is
>   \begin{align*}
> F(x)&=\frac{1}{1-dx-\text{weight}(\mathcal{C})}\\
> &=\frac{1}{1-2x+x^3}\\
> &=1+2x+4x^2+7x^3+12x^4+20x^5\\
> &\qquad+33x^6+54x^7+88x^8+143x^9+232x^{10}+\cdots\tag{1}
> \end{align*}
>
> The last line (1) was calculated with Wolfram Alpha and we see the coefficient of $x^8$ is $88$.

**We conclude:** out of $2^8=256$ binary strings of length $8$ there are precisely $88$ words which do not contain the substring $100$.

> Of course, we can also calculate the result by hand by expanding the generating function as *[geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Geometric_power_series)* and extracting the coefficient of $x^8$.
>
> In order to do so its convenient to use the *coefficient of* operator $[x^j]$ to denote the coefficient of $x^j$ of a series.
>
> We obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> [x^8]\frac{1}{1-2x+x^3}&=[x^8]\sum_{n=0}^\infty(2x-x^3)^n\tag{2}\\
> &=[x^8]\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n\sum_{j=0}^n\binom{n}{j}(-x^2)^j2^{n-j}\tag{3}\\
> &=\sum_{n=0}^8[x^{8-n}]\sum_{j=0}^n\binom{n}{j}(-1)^j2^{n-j}x^{2j}\tag{4}\\
> &=\binom{4}{2}(-1)^22^{4-2}+\binom{6}{1}(-1)^12^{6-1}+\binom{8}{0}(-1)^02^{8-0}\tag{5}\\
> &=6\cdot 4-6\cdot 32+1\cdot 256\\
> &=88
> \end{align*}
>   and the claim follows.

*Comment:*

- In (2) we expand the geometric series.
- In (3) we factor out $x^n$ and expand the binom using the formula $$(a-b)^n=\sum_{j=0}^n\binom{n}{j}(-b)^ja^{n-j}$$
- In (4) we use the linearity of the *coefficient of* operator and apply the formula $$[x^p]x^qA(x)=[x^{p-q}]A(x)$$ Since the exponent of $x^{8-n}$ is non-negative we restrict the upper limit of the sum with $8$.
- In (5) we select the coefficients of $x^{8-n}$. Since $0\leq j\leq n$ and the exponent of $x^{2j}$ is even, we need only to consider $n\in\{4,6,8\}$.

Comment: (+1). Nice to see a presentation of the best method, which really completes the page.  Why is it that you reversed the forbidden pattern? (Will delete comment if it is obvious. The word $0100$ contains the forbidden pattern as per the OP but it does not contain $001$, and yet it should be forbidden.)

Comment: @MarkoRiedel: Thanks Marko! Typo corrected!

Answer (score 1):

Consider 4 exclusive states a string can be in :

- (A) The string contains 100
- (B) The string ends in 10, but doesn't contain 100
- (C) The string ends in 1, but doesn't contain 100
- (D) None of the Above

Now consider a matrix representing transitions from the 4 states.  For example, if a string is in state (B), and the next bit is a 0, then the next state of the string is (A).  The transitions if the next bit is 0 are given by:

$$M_0 = \begin{array} {c|cccc}
  & A & B & C & D \\ \hline
A & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
B & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
C & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
D & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}$$

And the transitions if the next bit is a 1 :

$$M_1 = \begin{array} {c|cccc}
  & A & B & C & D \\ \hline
A & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
B & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
C & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
D & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
\end{array}$$

And initially the string is empty, so it is in state (D):

$$V = \begin{array} {cccc}
A & B & C & D \\ \hline
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 
\end{array}$$

The states reachable from the string of length $n$ is given by:

$$V(M_0 + M_1)^n$$

So for example, the strings of length 8 will have states:

$$V(M_0 + M_1)^8 = \begin{array} {cccc}
A & B & C & D \\ \hline
168 & 33 & 54 & 1 
\end{array}$$

168 strings will contain 100, 33 will end in 10 but not contain 100, 54 will end in 1 but not contain 100, and there will be 1 more string (the string containing all zeroes).  So there are $2^8 - 168 = 33 + 54 + 1 = 88$ strings not containing 100.

Answer (score 0):

No formal mathematics, but I thought I post because it may help you or someone else anyway.

This is a short function in the programming language Python that gives the number of `length`-bit binary strings not containing the binary substring `substring`.

```
def notContaining(length, substring):
"""
Gives the number of 'length'-bit strings not containing 'substring'.
"""
n = 2**length # number of 'length'-bit strings

for i in range(0, 2**length): # for every number having (maximal) 'length' bits
    if str(substring) in i: # if the substring is in the i-th 'length'-bit binary string
        n -= 1

return n
```

For `length = 1` and `substring = '100'` it returns `88`:

```
>>> notContaining(8, '100')
88
```

*If anyone notices me making a mistake here, it'd be thankful to know.*

Answer (score 0):

Let $C_n$ be the number of bit strings of length $n$ that *C*ontain $100$, and let $D_n$ be the number that *D*on't contain it.  Clearly $C_n+D_n=2^n$ and $C_1=C_2=0$.  For $n\ge3$, we have the following recursion:

$$C_n=\sum_{k=0}^{n-3}2^{n-3-k}D_k$$

where we define $D_0=1$.  The proof of the recursion is that if a string *C*ontains $100$, then its  *first* appearance will be preceded by a string of length at most $n-3$ that *D*oesn't contain $100$ and followed by an additional $n-3-k$ bits that can be anything.

We can now dispose of the $C_n$'s, writing $C_n=2^n-D_n$, so that

$$D_n=2^n-\sum_{k=0}^{n-3}2^{n-3-k}D_k$$

When $n$ gets larger, this becomes a cumbersome way to proceed, but for small values it's fairly efficient.  In particular,

$$D_8=2^8-(2^5D_0+2^4D_1+2^3D_2+2^2D_3+2D_4+D_5)$$

We already have $D_0=1$, $D_1=2$, and $D_2=4$, and it's easy to see that $D_3=7$, so it suffices to compute

$$D_4=2^4-(2D_0+D_1)=16-(2+2)=12$$
and
$$D_5=2^5-(4D_0+2D_1+D_2)=32-(4+4+4)=20$$ so that

$$D_8=256-(32+16\cdot2+8\cdot4+4\cdot7+2\cdot12+20)=88$$