# Ordered binary sequences of length n with no two consecutive 0's without using recursion

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

Given ordered sequences of 0's and 1's of length n. In how many of them no two 0's stand next to each other? Could you do if n=25.

I know this can be solved by using recursion.
I am not familiar with solving recurrence equations. Could this be done another way?

Comment: It would certainly not be easy as the answer is the Fibonacci series which can't really be expressed in terms of powers of natural numbers or combinations which are the answers you would expect using traditional methods.

Comment: Sorry about the mixup with 0's and 1's. I will edit that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The  *[Goulden-Jackson Cluster Method](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/9806036)* is a convenient method to derive a *[generating function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_function)* for problems of this kind.

> We consider words of length $n\geq 0$ built from an alphabet $$\mathcal{V}=\{0,1\}$$ and the set $\mathcal{B}=\{00\}$ of *bad* words which are not allowed to be part of the words we are looking for.
>
> We derive a function $F(x)$ with the coefficient of $x^n$ being  the number of wanted words of length $n$.
>   According to the paper (p.7) the generating function $F(x)$  is
>   \begin{align*}
> F(x)=\frac{1}{1-dx-\text{weight}(\mathcal{C})}
> \end{align*}
>   with $d=|\mathcal{V}|=2$, the size of the alphabet and with the *weight-numerator* $\mathcal{C}$ with
>   \begin{align*}
> \text{weight}(\mathcal{C})=\text{weight}(\mathcal{C}[00])
> \end{align*}
>
> We calculate according to the paper
>   \begin{align*}
> \text{weight}(\mathcal{C}[00])&=-x^2-\text{weight}(\mathcal{C}[00])x
> \end{align*}
>   \begin{align*}
> \text{weight}(\mathcal{C}[00])=-\frac{x^2}{1+x}\\
> \end{align*}

It follows:

> A generating function $F(x)$ for the number of words built from $\{0,1\}$ which do *not* contain the subword $00$ is
>   \begin{align*}
> F(x)&=\frac{1}{1-dx-\text{weight}(\mathcal{C})}\\
> &=\frac{1}{1-2x+\frac{x^2}{1+x}}\\
> &=\frac{1+x}{1-x-x^2}\\
> &=1+2x+3x^2+5x^3+8x^4+13x^5\\
> &\qquad+21x^6+34x^7+55x^8+89x^9+144x^{10}+\cdots\tag{1}
> \end{align*}
>
> The last line (1) was calculated with Wolfram Alpha and we see the coefficients  are the  *[Fibonacci numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number)* $F_n$  starting with $F_2=1$.

We  conclude: The generating function $F(x)$ is

\begin{align*}
\bbox[10px,border:2px solid blue]{
F(x)=\frac{1+x}{1-x-x^2}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty F_{n+2}x^n
}
\end{align*}

and the number of binary strings of length $n=25$ which do not contain the substring $00$ is the Fibonacci number

$$
\bbox[10px,border:2px solid blue]{
F_{27}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\left(\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^{27}-\left(\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^{27}\right)=196148
}
$$

$$ $$

> **Addon 2016-09-01:** Due to a comment of OP some details regarding the calculation of 
>   \begin{align*}
> \text{weight}(\mathcal{C}[00])=-\frac{x^2}{1+x}\tag{1}
> \end{align*}
>
> A **shortcut** of the following is indicated in a note at the end.

The main theme is to properly cope with *overlaps* of bad words. In order to do so we introduce some terminology. 
Let  $w=w_1w_2\ldots w_n$ be a word  consisting of $n$ characters. We define
\begin{align*}
weight(w)&:=x^{length(w)}=x^n\\
HEAD(w)&:=\{w_1,w_1w_2,\ldots,w_1w_2\ldots w_{n-1}\}\\
TAIL(w)&:=\{w_n,w_{n-1}w_n,\ldots,w_nw_{n-1}\ldots w_2\}\\
OVERLAP(u,v)&:=HEAD(u)\cap TAIL(v)
\end{align*}

> **Example: $w=00$**
>
> Since we have to consider only one  bad word $00$  we look at an example with $w=u=v=00$.
>
> We obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> weight(00)&=x^{length(00)}=x^2\\
> HEAD(00)&=\{0\}\\
> TAIL(00)&=\{0\}\\
> OVERLAP(00,00)&:=HEAD(00)\cap TAIL(00)=\{0\}\tag{2}
> \end{align*}

If $x\in HEAD(v)$ we write
\begin{align*}
v&=xx^\prime\\
v/x&:=x^\prime
\end{align*}
and we define for convenience $u:v$ as sum over all overlaps of two words $u$ and $v$. We sum up the weighted left-over parts $v/x$ when chopping overlaps.
\begin{align*}
u:v:=\sum_{x\in OVERLAP(u,v)}weight(v/x)
\end{align*}

> Note that according to (2) $$OVERLAP(00,00)=\{0\}$$ So, the calculation of $u:v$ with $u=v=00$ results in
>   \begin{align*}
> 00:00&=\sum_{x\in \{0\}}weight(00/x)\\
> &=weight(00/0)\\
> &=weight(0)\\
> &=x^{length(0)}\\
> &=x^1
> \end{align*}

Finally we find at the beginning of page 9 of the *[paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/9806036)* an identity for $weight(\mathcal{C}[v])$ with $Comp(v)$ defined as the set of *bad* words $u\in \mathcal{B}$ for which $OVERLAP(u,v)$ is non-empty.
\begin{align*}
weight(\mathcal{C}[v])=-weight(v)-\sum_{u\in Comp(v)}(u:v)\cdot weight\left(\mathcal{C}[u]\right)
\end{align*}

> We obtain with $v=00$
>   \begin{align*}
> weight(\mathcal{C}[00])&=-weight(00)-\sum_{u\in Comp(00)}(u:00)\cdot weight\left(\mathcal{C}[u]\right)\\
> &=-x^{length(00)}-\sum_{u\in \{00\}}(u:00)\cdot weight\left(\mathcal{C}[u]\right)\\
> &=-x^{length(00)}-(00:00)\cdot weight\left(\mathcal{C}[00]\right)\\
> &=-x^2-x^1\cdot weight\left(\mathcal{C}[00]\right)\tag{3}\\
> \end{align*}
>   and the claim (1) follows.

**Note:** Although the notation looks somewhat complicated. With     some routine you can skip nearly all of the calculations. We can deduce (3) quickly by observing that there is just one bad word $00$ resulting in a term $x^2$ and one overlap
\begin{align*}
0&0\\
00&\\
\end{align*}
resulting in a term $x^{length(0)}=x$.

**Note:** Another description of $HEAD, TAIL$ and $OVERLAP$ with the bad word $ABBA$ can be found in *[this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1782724/find-a-generating-function-for-the-number-of-strings/1783033#1783033)*.

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand how the function F(x) was derived in the paper. Thanks for letting me know about the article though.

Comment: @Amrita: I've added some explanations, which might be useful. Don't worry, if it is too complicated at the time. If so, then simply remember the keyword *cluster method* for future usage.

Answer (score 2):

Just to put in a defense of recursive methods:

Let $A_n$ be the number of "good" sequences of length $n$.  It is reasonably clear that any good sequence (of length at least $2$) ends in either $0$ or $01$.  Of course what precedes that ending must be a good sequence of shorter length.  Conversely, any good sequence of length $n-1$ becomes a good sequence of length $n$ if you append a $0$ and any good sequence of length $n-2$ becomes a good sequence of length $n$ if you append $01$. Thus we see that $$A_n=A_{n-1}+A_{n-2}$$  Which we recognize as the Fibonacci recursion.  Since $A_1=2$ and $A_2=3$ it is easy to generate $A_n$ for any modest $n$.  No need to solve the recursion (though of course that is possible).

Comment: So your suggestion for n=25 would be to use a computer program.

Comment: Well, that's instantaneous.  Pencil and paper is perfectly possible.  Or you could recognize this to be the (shifted) definition of the Fibonacci numbers.  My point, really, was that (at least to me)  the recursive methods greatly clarify how the good sequences are made.  If you were asked to actually enumerate them (with a computer), I'd say you'd want to do it this way.

Answer (score 0):

What follows is definitely more of a comment than an answer, providing
a hint  in case other  approaches prove  too difficult. Many  of these
types of problems can be solved with regular expressions. In your case
we have the regex $$1^* (01^+)^* (0|\epsilon).$$

Now  use $z$  for zeros  and  $w$ for  ones to  get the  generating
function

$$\frac{1}{1-w} \left(\sum_{q\ge 0} z^q \frac{w^q}{(1-w)^q}\right) 
(1+z).$$

This yields

$$\frac{1}{1-w} \frac{1}{1-zw/(1-w)} (1+z)
= \frac{1}{1-w-zw} (1+z).$$

As the requirements of the problem  only specify the count we may drop
the distinction between zeroes and ones at this point to obtain

$$\frac{1+z}{1-z-z^2}.$$

We may now continue as in the answer by @MarkusScheuer.

Comment: Sorry I am unable to understand how you got the generating function