# How many Binary Strings of length N contain within it the substring '11011'?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

I've been trying this for a long time. An example is:

N = 5. 
Then we can have 11011 which is only one substring.

But if N = 9,

We can have many binary strings in the form

11011xxxx 2^4 combinations

x11011xxx 2^4 combinations

xx11011xx 2^4 combinations

xxx11011x 2^4 combinations

xxxx11011 2^4 combinations

But this is the case of overcounting. (110110110) is one string, but is counted as 2.

How do we avoid this?

**Note: this question came in the 2016 ZIO.**

[ZIO2016](http://www.iarcs.org.in/inoi/2016/zio2016/zio2016-question-paper.pdf)

Comment: You can construct an automata for it: Here you have a construction of a generating function of your numbers.(section 1.4)
http://algo.inria.fr/flajolet/Publications/book.pdf

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here we are looking for binary strings of length $N$ which do *not* contain the substring $11011$. The result is then  $2^N$ *minus* this number.

> The so-called *[Goulden-Jackson Cluster Method](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/9806036)* is a convenient technique to derive a *[generating function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_function)* for problems of this kind.
>
> We consider words of length $N\geq 0$ built from an alphabet $$\mathcal{V}=\{0,1\}$$ and the set $\mathcal{B}=\{11011\}$ of *bad* words which are not allowed to be part of the words we are looking for.
>
> We derive a function $F(x)$ with the coefficient of $x^N$ being  the number of wanted words of length $n$.
>   According to the paper (p.7) the generating function $F(x)$  is
>   \begin{align*}
> F(x)=\frac{1}{1-dx-\text{weight}(\mathcal{C})}
> \end{align*}
>   with $d=|\mathcal{V}|=2$, the size of the alphabet and with the *weight-numerator* $\mathcal{C}$ with
>   \begin{align*}
> \text{weight}(\mathcal{C})=\text{weight}(\mathcal{C}[11011])
> \end{align*}
>
> We calculate according to the paper
>   \begin{align*}
> \text{weight}(\mathcal{C}[11011])&=-x^5-\text{weight}(\mathcal{C}[11011])\left(x^3+x^4\right)
> \end{align*}

It follows:
A generating function $F(x)$ for the number of words built from $\{0,1\}$ which do *not* contain the subword $11011$ is
\begin{align*}
F(x)&=\frac{1}{1-dx-\text{weight}(\mathcal{C})}\\
&=\frac{1}{1-2x+\frac{x^5}{1+x^3+x^4}}\\
&=\frac{1+x^3+x^4}{1-2x+x^3-x^4-x^5}
\end{align*}

Since the generating function counting the number $2^N$ of all binary strings of length $N$ is
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{1-2x}=1+2x+4x^2+\cdots
\end{align*}

> **We conclude:** A generating function for the number binary strings of length $N$ which contain the string $11011$ is
>
> \begin{align*}
> \frac{1}{1-2x}-F(x)&=\frac{1}{1-2x}-\frac{1+x^3+x^4}{1-2x+x^3-x^4-x^5}\\
> &=\frac{x^5}{(1-2x)(1-2x+x^3-x^4-x^5)}\\
> &=x^5+4x^6+12x^7+31x^8+75x^9+175x^{10}\\
> &\qquad 399x^{11}+894x^{12}+1975x^{13}+4313x^{14}+9330x^{15}+\cdots
> \end{align*}
>
> The last line (1) was calculated with the help of Wolfram Alpha and we see the number of solutions of strings with length up to $N=15$.

For example the $12$ strings of length $7$ containing the substring $11011$ are

\begin{array}{cccc}
\color{blue}{00}11011\quad&\quad\color{blue}{0}11011\color{blue}{0}\quad&\quad11011\color{blue}{00}\\
\color{blue}{01}11011\quad&\quad\color{blue}{0}11011\color{blue}{1}\quad&\quad11011\color{blue}{01}\\
\color{blue}{10}11011\quad&\quad\color{blue}{1}11011\color{blue}{0}\quad&\quad11011\color{blue}{10}\\
\color{blue}{11}11011\quad&\quad\color{blue}{1}11011\color{blue}{1}\quad&\quad11011\color{blue}{11}\\
\end{array}

Comment: An exhaustive answer and of wide interest! always nice to learn from your posts, Markus, thanks

Comment: @GCab:  Many thanks  for your nice comment! :-)

Comment: (+1). This is very nice work. You'll be happy to know that the [DFA-method](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1782724/) yields the same answer with the command **factor(1/(1-2*z)-GFNC([[1,1,0,1,1]], 2, true));**.

Comment: @MarkoRiedel: Thanks a lot, Marko! I've also checked it with a little piece of R code. But, not that elegant as your part is. :-)

Comment: Code can be an instructive enrichment of mathematical posts, permitting effective communication of simple ideas that would otherwise require a great deal of notation.

Comment: @MarkoRiedel: I fully agree! In fact I'm used to check my   calculation activities since I'm working in a safety related business. Regards,

Comment: @MarkusScheuer There is a user at this [MSE link](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1926107/) who is asking for a proof of a theorem without using complex analysis, maybe you could have a look as you have presented a number of formal power series proofs lately.

Comment: @MarkoRiedel: Many thanks for the hint, Marko. I will take a look at it.

Answer (score 2):

Let $k$ be the number of blocks of 11011, let $j$ be the number of single overlaps of the blocks (giving $110111011$), and let $l$ be the number of double overlaps (giving $11011011$).

Then there are $\binom{k-1}{j}$ ways to choose the single overlaps, $\binom{k-1-j}{l}$ ways to choose the double overlaps,

$\binom{n-4k+l}{k-j-l}$ ways to choose the positions of the blocks (since there are $k-j-l$ dividers

and $n-5k+j+2l$ remaining digits), and $2^{n-5k+j+2l}$ ways to choose the other digits.

Using Inclusion-Exclusion, this gives $$\sum_{k=1}^{\lfloor\frac{n-2}{3}\rfloor}(-1)^{k+1}\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}\sum_{l=0}^{k-1-j}\binom{k-1}{j}\binom{k-1-j}{l}\binom{n-4k+l}{k-j-l}2^{n-5k+j+2l}$$.