# Convolution Identity for Stirling Numbers

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients, stirling-numbers

Trying to prove the following identity (obtained from a problem in statistical mechanics):

\begin{equation}
S(\ell, m) = \sum_{k=m}^{\ell}\binom{k}{m}
\sum_{i=0}^{k}(-1)^{\ell+i} \,S(\ell + i - m, k)\, s(k, i) \,\binom{\ell}{\ell+i-m}, 
\end{equation}

where $S$ and $s$ denote Stirling numbers of the second and first kind, respectively.

I tested the identity in Mathematica and it yielded true values for $0 \leq m\leq \ell \leq 50$ so I think it's true in general, but I haven't seen it in any relevant texts (I've checked Gould's *Combinatorial Identities* and Roman's *Umbral Calculus*).

It also doesn't seem to easily reduce to any standard convolution identities (like 23. and 24. in http://mathworld.wolfram.com/StirlingNumberoftheSecondKind.html or 19, 23, 27, or 33 in http://dlmf.nist.gov/26.8#SS4.info)

Could anyone construct a combinatorial proof?

Comment: the first kind Stirlings are signed? or you took away the sign?

Comment: The Stirling numbers of the first kind in the equation are signed. $s(2,1)$ = -1, for example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Suppose we seek to verify that

$${n\brace m} =
\sum_{k=m}^n {k\choose m}
\sum_{q=0}^k (-1)^{n+q} 
{n+q-m\brace k}
(-1)^{k+q} \left[k\atop q\right] {n\choose n+q-m}$$

which is

$${n\brace m} = (-1)^n
\sum_{k=m}^n {k\choose m} (-1)^k
\sum_{q=0}^k 
{n+q-m\brace k}
\left[k\atop q\right] {n\choose m-q}$$

where presumably  $n\ge m.$  We need  for the second binomial coefficient
that $m\ge q$ so this is

$${n\brace m} = (-1)^n
\sum_{k=m}^n {k\choose m} (-1)^k
\sum_{q=0}^m
{n+q-m\brace k}
\left[k\atop q\right] {n\choose m-q}.$$

Observe  that the  Stirling number  of the  second kind  vanishes when
$k\gt n$ so we may extend the summation to infinity, getting

$${n\brace m} = (-1)^n
\sum_{k\ge m} {k\choose m} (-1)^k
\sum_{q=0}^m
{n+q-m\brace k}
\left[k\atop q\right] {n\choose m-q}.$$

Recall that

$$\left[k\atop q\right] = [w^q] k! \times {w+k-1\choose k}.$$

Starting  with the inner sum we obtain

$$n! \sum_{q=0}^m
\frac{1}{(m-q)!}
[z^{n+q-m}] (\exp(z)-1)^k 
[w^q] {w+k-1\choose k}
\\ = n! \sum_{q=0}^m
\frac{1}{q!}
[z^{n-q}] (\exp(z)-1)^k 
[w^{m-q}] {w+k-1\choose k}.$$

Now when $q\gt m$ the coefficient  extractor in $w$ yields zero, hence
we may extend the sum in $q$ to infinity:

$$n! \sum_{q\ge 0}
\frac{1}{q!}
[z^{n-q}] (\exp(z)-1)^k 
[w^{m-q}] {w+k-1\choose k}.$$

We thus obtain

$$\frac{n!}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{1}{z^{n+1}}
(\exp(z)-1)^k 
\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\gamma} \frac{1}{w^{m+1}}
{w+k-1\choose k}
\sum_{q\ge 0} \frac{1}{q!} z^q w^q
\; dw \; dz
\\ = \frac{n!}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{1}{z^{n+1}}
(\exp(z)-1)^k 
\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\gamma} \frac{1}{w^{m+1}}
{w+k-1\choose k}
\exp(zw)
\; dw \; dz.$$

Preparing the outer sum we obtain

$$\sum_{k\ge m} {k\choose m} (-1)^k
(\exp(z)-1)^k {w+k-1\choose k}
\\ = \sum_{k\ge m} {k\choose m} (-1)^k
(\exp(z)-1)^k [v^k] \frac{1}{(1-v)^w}.$$

Note that for a formal power series $Q(v)$ we have

$$\sum_{k\ge m} {k\choose m} (-1)^{k-m} u^{k-m} [v^k] Q(v)
= \frac{1}{m!} \left.(Q(v))^{(m)}\right|_{v=-u}.$$

We get for the derivative in $v$

$$\left(\frac{1}{(1-v)^w}\right)^{(m)} = 
m! {w+m-1\choose m} \frac{1}{(1-v)^{w+m}}.$$

Substituting $u=\exp(z)-1$ yields

$$m! {w+m-1\choose m} \exp(-(w+m)z).$$

Returning to the double integral we find

$$\frac{(-1)^n\times n!}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{1}{z^{n+1}}
(\exp(z)-1)^m (-1)^m
\\ \times
\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\gamma} \frac{1}{w^{m+1}}
\exp(zw)
{w+m-1\choose m} \exp(-(w+m)z)
\; dw \; dz
\\ = \frac{(-1)^n\times n!}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{1}{z^{n+1}}
(\exp(z)-1)^m (-1)^m \exp(-mz)
\\ \times
\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\gamma} \frac{1}{w^{m+1}}
{w+m-1\choose m} 
\; dw \; dz
\\ = \frac{(-1)^n\times n!}{2\pi i \times m!}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{1}{z^{n+1}}
(\exp(z)-1)^m (-1)^m \exp(-mz) \; dz
\\ = \frac{(-1)^n\times n!}{2\pi i \times m!}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{1}{z^{n+1}}
(1-\exp(-z))^m (-1)^m \; dz
\\ = \frac{(-1)^n\times n!}{2\pi i \times m!}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{1}{z^{n+1}}
(\exp(-z)-1)^m  \; dz.$$

Finally put $z=-v$ to get

$$-\frac{(-1)^n\times n!}{2\pi i \times m!}
\int_{|v|=\epsilon} \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{v^{n+1}}
(\exp(v)-1)^m  \; dv
\\ = \frac{n!}{2\pi i \times m!}
\int_{|v|=\epsilon} \frac{1}{v^{n+1}}
(\exp(v)-1)^m  \; dv.$$

This is

$$n! [v^n] \frac{(\exp(v)-1)^m}{m!} = {n\brace m}$$

and we have the claim.

Comment: I lack familiarity with the methods to verify this, but I was looking for a derivation which didn't use complex analysis.

Comment: Note that we have activity on your post, which I consider an advantage. You can always put a bounty on it in order to bring it to the attention of MSE combinatorics wizards. Another proof may yet appear.

Comment: Actually this proof is fine. Thank you Marko.

Answer (score 5):

**Note:** This is a rather challenging identity. The following is inspired by an in-depth analysis of the answer of @MarkoRiedel which was of great help to overcome some difficulties.

This answer is based upon the *coefficient of* operator $[z^n]$ to denote the coefficient of $z^n$ in a series. This way we can write e.g.
\begin{align*}
[z^k](1+z)^n=\binom{n}{k}
\end{align*}

Here we use D. Knuth's notational convention and write  $\left[n\atop k\right]$ for the *[unsigned Stirling numbers of the first kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_first_kind#Unsigned_Stirling_numbers_of_the_first_kind)* and ${n\brace k}$ for the *[Stirling numbers of the second  kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind)*.

From generating functions we get
\begin{align*}
\left[k\atop i\right]=[z^k]n!\binom{z+n-1}{n}\qquad\text{and}\qquad
{n\brace k}=n![z^n]\frac{\left(e^z-1\right)^k}{k!}\\
\end{align*}

> The following is valid for $0\leq m\leq l$
>
> \begin{align*}
> {l\brace m}=\sum_{k=m}^l\binom{k}{m}\sum_{i=0}^k(-1)^{l+k}{l+i-m\brace k}\left[k\atop i\right]\binom{l}{l+i-m}
> \end{align*}

Note that here is the sign $(-1)^{l+k}$ whereas in OPs formula the sign is $(-1)^{l+i}$. This is due to $s(k,i)=(-1)^{k+i}\left[k\atop i\right]$.

> We obtain
>
> \begin{align*}
> \sum_{k=m}^l&\binom{k}{m}\sum_{i=0}^k(-1)^{l+k}{l+i-m\brace k}\left[k\atop i\right]\binom{l}{l+i-m}\\
> &=\sum_{k=m}^l\binom{k}{m}\sum_{i=0}^m(-1)^{l+k}{l-i\brace k}\left[k\atop m-i\right]\binom{l}{i}\tag{1}\\
> &=\sum_{k\geq m}\binom{k}{m}\sum_{i\geq 0}(-1)^{l+k}(l-i)![z^{l-i}]\frac{\left(e^z-1\right)^k}{k!}
> [u^{m-i}]k!\binom{u+k-1}{k}\binom{l}{i}\tag{2}\\
> &=\sum_{k\geq m}\binom{k}{m}\sum_{i\geq 0}(-1)^{l+k}[z^{l-i}]\left(e^z-1\right)^k
> [u^{m-i}]\binom{-u}{k}(-1)^k\frac{l!}{i!}\tag{3}\\
> &=(-1)^ll!\sum_{k\geq m}\binom{k}{m}[z^{l}]\left(e^z-1\right)^k
> [u^{m}][t^k](1+t)^{-u}\sum_{i\geq 0}\frac{(zu)^i}{i!}\tag{4}\\
> &=(-1)^ll![z^{l}][u^{m}]e^{zu}\sum_{k\geq m}\binom{k}{m}\left(e^z-1\right)^k
> [t^k](1+t)^{-u}\tag{5}\\
> &=(-1)^ll![z^{l}][u^{m}]e^{zu}\left(e^z-1\right)^m\frac{1}{m!}D_t^m\left.(1+t)^{-u}\right|_{t=e^z-1}\tag{6}\\
> &=(-1)^ll![z^{l}][u^{m}]e^{zu}\left(e^z-1\right)^m(-1)^m\binom{u+m-1}{m}\left.(1+t)^{-(u+m)}\right|_{t=e^z-1}\tag{7}\\
> &=(-1)^{l}l![z^{l}]\left(e^z-1\right)^me^{-mz}(-1)^m[u^{m}]\binom{u+m-1}{m}\tag{8}\\
> &=(-1)^ll![z^{l}]\left(e^{-z}-1\right)^m\frac{1}{m!}\tag{9}\\
> &=l![z^{l}]\frac{\left(e^{z}-1\right)^m}{m!}\tag{10}\\
> &={l\brace m}
> \end{align*}
>   and the claim follows.

*Comment:*

- In (1) we set the upper limit of the inner sum to $m$  since $k\geq m$ and therefore $\binom{l}{l+i-m}=0$ for $i\geq m$. We also change the order of the inner sum by $i\rightarrow m-i$.
- In (2) we apply the *coefficient of* operator twice to the Stirling numbers of the first and second kind. We also set the upper limit of both sums to $\infty$ without changing anything since we are adding zeros only.
- In (3) we do some cancellation and use the binomial identity $$\binom{-p}{q}=\binom{p+q-1}{q}(-1)^q$$
- In (4) we do some rearrangements and apply the rule
  \begin{align*}
  [z^{p-q}]A(z)=[z^p]z^qA(z)
  \end{align*}
- In (5) we do some rearrangements and expand the exponential series.
- In (6) we recall the substitution rule of the *coefficient of* operator
  \begin{align*}
  A(z)=\sum_{k\geq 0} a_k z^k=\sum_{k\geq 0} z^k [t^k]A(t)
  \end{align*}
  Using the differential operator $D_z:=\frac{d}{dz}$ and apply it $m$ times we obtain
  \begin{align*}
  D_z^mA(z)&=\sum_{k\geq m} k(k-1)\cdots (k-m+1)a_k z^{k-m}\\
  &=m!\sum_{k\geq m}\binom{k}{m}a_kz^{k-m}\\
  &=m!\sum_{k\geq m}\binom{k}{m}z^{k-m}[t^k]A(t)
  \end{align*}

It follows using the substitution $t:= e^z-1$
\begin{align*}
\sum_{k\geq m}\binom{k}{m}\left(e^z-1\right)^{k-m}[t^k](1+t)^{-u}
=\frac{1}{m!}D_t^m\left.(1+t)^{-u}\right|_{t=e^z-1}
\end{align*}

- In (7) we do the differentiation.
- In (8) we substitute and simplify
- In (9) we select the coefficient of $u^m$ from the *polynomial* $\binom{u+m-1}{m}$ in $u$ and simplify the expression.
- In (10) we substitute $z\rightarrow -z$.

Comment: This is amazing! I hope it is sound (will check later). (+1). Line 10 seems to be missing a sign flip.

Comment: @MarkoRiedel: Oh, yes! I see! It's already a litte bit late. But great review Marko! Many thanks. I think the proof is now consistent.

Comment: I agree that it has now been vetted. Congratulations on establishing a reference document! Potential readers should really profit from these two different versions.  Which of the comments would you like to remove?

Comment: @MarkoRiedel: Besides that minor technical stuff. The interesting part of the proof was to recognize that it is advantageous to keep the binomial coefficient $\binom{k}{m}$ and use differentiation instead of transforming the sum to start from $k=0$ and working with $\binom{k}{m}=[w^k](1+w)^m$ which led to nowhere. Thanks for that!