# Find linear recurrence for set constructed by Bernoulli trial

Tags: probability, recurrence-relations, bernoulli-numbers

Got such a task at the exam. Any ideas how to solve it?

---

Consider the set $ \{1,\dots,n\} $.
Lets perform sequential pairwise independent Bernoulli trials with success probability $ \frac{1}{2}$.

*If we get success at $\textbf{i}$**-step**, we take $\textbf{i}$ out  and put into the projected set $A$ then go to $i+1$th trial. If not, we simply go on to the next trial.*

In the end we get a random set $A$ consisting of the elements that were taken out.  It can be either null or equal to all set  $\{1,\dots,n\}$, or be any other.

The difference of two sets $A,B\subset \{0,1,2,\ldots,n-1\}$ is a set  $A-B=\{a-b:a\in A, b\in B\}$ (the difference of two elements of this set is considered as the difference of two natural number.
Note that $A-B$ can contain elements that don't belong to the set $\{0,1,\ldots, n-1\}$, but always is a subset of $\{-n+1,-n+2,\ldots,n-2,n-1\}.$.

**Take the set $A$ randomly generated by the scheme described above and find linear recurrence equation with constant coefficients at probability** $p_n={\rm P}(3\notin A-A)$

---

As I understood it means that the set A should not contain two objects the difference between which equals 3.

I tried to consider options when the last $n-1$ element is or is not included in the resulting set $A$ but didn't move any further than $p_n = \frac{1}{2} p_{n-1} + something$.  $something$ is when $n-1$ is in set $A$.

---

**Edit:** With help of @GCab I tried to process binary string recursively from the end and got such recurrence: 
$p_n = \frac{1}{2} p_{n-1} + \frac{1}{2}(\frac{1}{2}(\frac{1}{2} p_{n-6}+ \frac{1}{2}p_{n-5}) + \frac{1}{2}(\frac{1}{2}d_{n-2} + \frac{1}{2}p_{n-3}))$  where $d_k = \frac{1}{2}d_{k-2} + \frac{1}{2}p_{k-2}$ Is it correct? It seems to me a little bit strange, ohh inner recurrence?

Comment: *... If not we go on to next trial* : that seems to mean that $A$ only contains one element, the index of the first success. You shall reword you statement, probably

Comment: 2) if $3 \in (A-A)$ then also $-3 \in (A-A)$, right?

Comment: @GCab I correct statement. And yes, you right. But I don't think that this can help)

Answer (score 1):

The comment about $|3|$ is instead helpful.
That means that you can take your sequence of trials as a binary string of length $n$.
Then your problem becomes to count the strings that do (/ do not) have
*(amended thanks to Ian's comment)*
** two $1$'s separated by exactly two characters whichever, i.e. the $(1,x,x,1)$ subsequence**.
because you are taking the difference between any two elements of $A$, which therefore could contain other successes in between.
If you were taking the difference between two *consecutive* elements of $A$, then the pattern would be $(1,0,0,1)$.

That premised, we are dealing with the general problem of finding the number of strings (in this case, binary)
that contain a given substring or set of substrings.
It is not an easy task, but there is a general approach as described in M_ Scheuer's answer to [this post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1920508).
Also the number of strings containing the substring $(1,x,x,1)$ is the [OEIS seq. V](http://oeis.org/A209399).

Comment: I added possible answer in question based on your hint but it seems strange to me =) Check it plz

Comment: I think one of us is misunderstanding the problem: in my understanding you want there to be no 1xx1 subsequences, where x can be 0 or 1.

Comment: @Ian Yes, no numbers with difference equal 3, it means no `1001`

Comment: @Ian: you are right, actually the pattern to avoid is $1,x,x,1$, thanks for signalling.