# What is the number of series $(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5,x_6,x_7) \in \{0,1,2\}^7$ that do not contain the sequence $010$ in any three consecutive places?

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions, inclusion-exclusion, combinatorics-on-words

> What is the number of series $(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5,x_6,x_7) \in
>  \{0,1,2\}^7$ that do not contain the sequence $010$ in any three
> consecutive places?

Hello!
I have the following question in my assignment. I managed to solve it using inclusion- exclusion principle, but it was a very tedious process.

Is there any elegant way to solve this?

if not, for practice I would like to solve it with generating functions as well, but I was not sure how, so a hint on how to look at this question in a generating function approach would be highly appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: I’d use inclusion and exclusion, but it doesn’t seem that tedious to me.  You can use symmetry to make the counting a little easier.

Comment: Another approach is to count walks with $6$ nodes in a directed graph with node set $\{0,1,2\}^2$ and all possible arcs $(i,j)\to(j,k)$ except $(0,1)\to(1,0)$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** A technique to solve such problems is the *[Goulden-Jackson Cluster Method](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/9806036)*.

> We consider the set words of length $n\geq 0$ built from an alphabet $$\mathcal{V}=\{0,1,2\}$$ and the set $B=\{010\}$ of *bad words*, which are not allowed to be part of the words we are looking for. We derive a generating function $f(s)$ with the coefficient of $s^n$ being  the number of searched words of length $n$.

A proof providing the solution $\color{blue}{1\,817}$ valid words of length $7$ which do not contain $010$ is given *[here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1938767/recursion-problem-ternary-words-not-containing-121/1939491#1939491)*. We can take the proof as it is, simply replacing every occurrence of the *bad* word $121$ with $010$ there.