# Find the number of ways in which  coin tosses can be made such that there are not three consecutive heads or tails.

Tags: combinatorics

Find the number of ways in which  coin tosses can be made such that there are not three consecutive heads or tails.

actually I think THT TTH HHT HTH possibilities and the recursive relation but I dont know how can I express them ??

Comment: Although OP shows no work, please don't close this, since it is an interesting problem and tough enough that it is probably not just some homework assignment.

Comment: Please show us what you know or have tried. Despite the interesting problem, we need to know what you know and what approaches haven't worked.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider creating a string of H and T of length $k$ by adding one toss to the previous string of length $k-1$.

Let $P_k$ be the number of strings of length $k$ that contain no triplets and end in TH or HT.

Let $M_k$ be the number of strings of length $k$ that contain no triplets and end in TT or HH. Thus the number we desire is $N_k = P_k + M_k$.

But while either toss can be added to $P_{k-1}$ only one specific toss leads to a $P_k$ string; another toss leads to an $M_k$ string. And only one specific toss can be added to an $M_{k-1}$ string; it leades to a $P_k$ string.   Thus

$$P_k = P_{k-1} + M_{k-1} \\ M_k = P_{k-1}$$

Then $$P_k = P_{k-1} + P_{k-2}$$

This is the equation determining the Fibonacci sequence; the starting conditions are that $P_2 = 2, P_3 = 6$.  So

$$P_k = 2F_k$$
 where $F_k$ is the $k$-th Fibonacci number.  And then

$$ N_k = 2 F_{k+1}$$

Comment: I think you have a typo; you mean $P_3 = 6$, not $P_4 = 6$

Answer (score 3):

The so-called *[Goulden-Jackson Cluster Method](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/9806036)* is a convenient technique to derive a *[generating function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_function)* for problems of this kind.

> We consider the set of binary words of length $n\geq 0$  and the set $B=\{HHH,TTT\}$ of *bad* words, which are not allowed to be part of the words we are looking for. We derive a generating function $f(s)$ with the coefficient of $s^n$ being  the number of wanted words of length $n$.
>
> According to the paper (p.7) from Goulden and Jackson the generating function $f(s)$  is
>   \begin{align*}
> f(s)=\frac{1}{1-ds-\text{weight}(\mathcal{C})}\tag{1}
> \end{align*}
>   with $d=|\mathcal{V}|=2$, the size of the alphabet and with the *weight-numerator* $\mathcal{C}$ with
>   \begin{align*}
> \text{weight}(\mathcal{C})=\text{weight}(\mathcal{C}[HHH])+\text{weight}(\mathcal{C}[TTT])
> \end{align*}
>   We calculate according to the paper
>   \begin{align*}
> \text{weight}(\mathcal{C}[HHH])&=\text{weight}(\mathcal{C}[TTT])\\
> &=-\frac{s^3}{1+s+s^2}=-\frac{s^3(1-s)}{1-s^3}\\
> \end{align*}

and

> we obtain the generating function $f(s)$ for the binary words which do not contain the bad words
>   \begin{align*}
> f(s)&=\frac{1}{1-2s+\frac{2s^3(1-s)}{1-s^3}}\\
> &=\frac{2}{1-s-s^2}-1\\
> &=1+2s+4s^2+6s^3+10s^4+16s^5+26s^6+42s^7+\cdots
> \end{align*}

Note, the result is essentially twice the generating function of the *[Fibonacci numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number)* 
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{1-s-s^2}
\end{align*}

Answer (score 2):

The [DFA method](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1782724/) (which is the naive approach) will produce the following transcript, matching the answer by @MarkusScheuer.

```
> GFNC([[0,0,0],[1,1,1]], 2, true);
                            [[1, 1, 1], [0, 0, 0]]

                                 Q[], 0, Q[0]

                                 Q[], 1, Q[1]

                               Q[0], 0, Q[0, 0]

                                 Q[0], 1, Q[1]

                            Q[0, 0], 0, Q[0, 0, 0]

                               Q[0, 0], 1, Q[1]

                           Q[0, 0, 0], 0, Q[0, 0, 0]

                           Q[0, 0, 0], 1, Q[0, 0, 0]

                                 Q[1], 0, Q[0]

                               Q[1], 1, Q[1, 1]

                               Q[1, 1], 0, Q[0]

                            Q[1, 1], 1, Q[1, 1, 1]

                           Q[1, 1, 1], 0, Q[1, 1, 1]

                           Q[1, 1, 1], 1, Q[1, 1, 1]

                                    2
                                   z  + z + 1
                                 - ----------
                                    2
                                   z  + z - 1

> series(%, z=0, 9);
                  2      3       4       5       6       7       8      9
     1 + 2 z + 4 z  + 6 z  + 10 z  + 16 z  + 26 z  + 42 z  + 68 z  + O(z )
```

We can also derive this  from first principles, getting the generating
function (use $z$ for heads and $w$ for tails):

$$f(z,w) = (1+z+z^2) 
\left(\sum_{q\ge 0} (w+w^2)^q (z+z^2)^q\right) (1+w+w^2).$$

This simplifies to

$$(1+z+z^2) \frac{1}{1-w(w+1)z(z+1)} (1+w+w^2).$$

Now  we  are  only  interested  in  the count,  so  we  may  drop  the
distinction between heads amd tails to get

$$\frac{(1+z+z^2)^2}{1-z^2(1+z)^2}
= \frac{(1+z+z^2)^2}{(1+z(1+z))(1-z(1+z))}
= \frac{1+z+z^2}{1-z-z^2}.$$

This is the same generating function as before.

Comment: Clear and concise derivation! (+1)

Comment: Goulden-Jackson is the winning ticket. DFA used here only to verify correctness of result.

Comment: Thanks Marko. In my comment I refer especially to the derivation of the generating function. :-)

Answer (score 0):

this is easy using recursion, suppose $f_n$ is the desired number. We have $f_1=2,f_2=4$. And for $n> 2$ we have:

The desired sequences of length $n$ can be separated into $2$ types:

The ones in which the last two flips are different ( there are $f_{n-1}$ of this type).

The ones in which the last three flips are all the same ( there are $f_{n-3}$ of this type).

We hence have the recursion $f_n=f_{n-1}+f_{n-2}$

Comment: if the last three flips are the same then wouldn't it violate the condition of not having 3 consecutive H or T?

Comment: Based on your answer $f_4=12$ but it should be $10$ because out of $16$ possible strings we cannot have HHHH, TTTT, HTTT, TTTH, HHHT, THHH.

Comment: For length $4$ the "bad" strings are $H^4,T^4,TH^3,H^3T,HT^3,T^3H$.  Hence $f_4=16-6=10$, no?  I think your type three does not exist.

Comment: oh yeah, I accidentally solved for four consecutive instead of three. It is fixed now